# MySql row insertion issue, table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am getting a pretty strange error/bug in phpMyAdmin when trying to insert a new row.

When I try to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `Appointment` (`Customer_ID_FK`, `Consult_ID_FK`, `Date`) 
VALUES (1, 1, NOW())
```

I get the following error back:

> #1146 - Table 'waspbane_Libra.CT' doesn't exist

I have seriously no idea what is going on here and why it asks for a table called CT. I have no such table in my database so of course it would throw an error on that, but why would it convert the table name `Appointment` into `CT`?

The table uses innoDB with 2 foreign keys to other tables.

Image of the database scheme from phpMyAdmin: http://prntscr.com/bwvbtk

Comment: Do you have any triggers which might try to insert to CT?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that was the problem. I forgot the fact I had an old trigger but I never removed it. I'll re-post it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue thanks to P.Salmon.

The problem was an old trigger in the table which was no longer of any use and that one was trying to insert to a table called CT (The table called Consult referenced as CT). So I removed the trigger and now it works.